# MinGW GCC wildcard

Tags: windows, gcc, mingw, wildcard

I'm using MinGW GCC compiler on windows how to compile all C files in a directory.

I used

```
gcc  *.c -o  Output
```

after I entered the required folder and I got this error

```
gcc: error: *.c: Invalid argument 
gcc: fatal error: no input files
```

compilation terminated.

the used version of GCC is 4.7.1

Comment: Either you have no `.c` files, or you didn't type this at a shell prompt.  (You can't put that as the options in code::blocks, for example). If you are still having trouble the explain more about how you sent the command and what shell you are using.

Comment: I use windows CMD and I add the mingw bin folder to the system PATH variable and  I could use gcc --version command 
and I check out the folder that folder have no file except .c files

Comment: well - works for me using mingw-w64 4.9.2, and windows cmd.  Hopefully someone else can reproduce your problem. Consider using [mingw-w64](http://www.mingw-w64.org/) anyway.

Comment: I've tested and it works correctly with gcc 6.1.0 (I'm using mingw-w64).

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else like me who's come across this problem:

I ran into this problem when I installed MinGW-w64 on my tablet after having run it for a few years on my desktop.
Basically, I have a ruby script that does some basic compilation stuff for me, and it was breaking at the linking stage on my tablet (developed on, and ran fine on the desktop).
The error: Invalid Argument, no input files (as in the original question).

If you check around, you'll find a few places that tell you that the issue is due to the way CMD on Windows handles passing wildcards to programs (vs UNIX shells).
Basically Windows leaves interpretation of the wildcard up to the program.
Some builds of MinGW can handle a wildcard from CMD, whereas others won't.
  I'm able to use wildcards using the MinGW-W64-builds installer for MinGW-W64.

Answer (score 0):

This should work with older mingw-w64 versions:

```
#ifdef __MINGW64_VERSION_MAJOR
int _dowildcard = -1; /* enable wildcard expansion for mingw-w64 */
#endif
```